# "undefined method 'value'" when looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I am trying to loop through a list of tags returned from AWS API, but I'm getting "undefined method 'value'. I can provide further information if needed.

This is my simple loop:

```
@instances.each do |i| 
 t = 0 
   while i.tags.any? do 
     puts i.tags[t].value 
    t += 1 
   end 
end
```

Comment: Will you please show what you are getting in `@instances` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i.tags.any?` returns `true` as soon as `tags.compact` array is not empty. So, you enter the endless loop and sooner or later `t` becomes greater than `tags.length`. Call to `tags[tags.length]` returns `nil`, and calling `value` on `nil` produces the error you got.

The loop you likely wanted looks like:

```
i.tags.each do |tag|
  puts tag.value
end
```

Comment: Perfect. Sorry, if this was a bit too easy. :)